# Pointer to pointer , values not updating

Tags: c, pointers

**global.h**

```
typedef enum _global_list {
    TEST_VAR1,
    TEST_VAR2
} list;

/*Mapper between enum varibales and global variable*/
typedef struct _var_map{
    list list_type;
    void *ptr;
} var_map;

/*struct to hold global variable*/
typedef struct _glo_ptr{
    int *ptr1;
    float *ptr2;
} g_ptr;
g_ptr ptr;
void update_global(list ,void *);
```

**global.c**

```
#include "globals.h"

static var_map map[2] = { { TEST_VAR1, &(ptr.ptr1) }, { TEST_VAR2, &ptr.ptr2 } };

update_global(list var, void* ptr){

    if (map[0].list_type == TEST_VAR1){
        map[0].ptr =  ptr;
    }
}
```

**testfile.c**

```
#include "globals.h"
int main(){
    int test_var1=0;
    update_global(TEST_VAR1, &test_var1);
    test_var1=4;
    printf("%d",*ptr.ptr1); //should contain value 4
}
```

What I'm trying to do is: my `g_ptr` should contain latest values pointed by it.  But in  pointer to pointer I'm doing somewhere some mistake leading not proper update of values. For exmple: my final `g_ptr.ptr1` value should contain 4.  What needs to be corrected in this?

Comment: update() has no return value?

Comment: Nick:It's global value which I'm trying to access.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is you're changing the actual pointer in your map, but not affecting the data being pointed to:

```
map[0].ptr =  ptr;
```

Should be:

```
*(int**)map[0].ptr =  (int*)ptr;
```

The motivation behind your program is a little suspect, but I believe this will give you what you are looking for...  I will keep my distance =)

Oh, I noticed another thing...  You declare separate instances of `ptr`.  When you include `global.h` in each source file, they see `ptr` as a private static variable.  That's not what you want.  You need to declare and define it like this:

**global.h**

```
extern g_ptr ptr;
```

**global.c**

```
g_ptr ptr;
```

Comment: Please note I have updated my answer after noticing something else